# Is "would I could" idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, idioms

This excerpt came from [The Confidence-Man](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/m/melville/herman/confidence-man/chapter4.html) (1857) from Herman Melville:

> Oh, the cripple. Poor fellow. I know him well. They found me. I have said all I could for him. I think I abated their distrust. **Would I could** have been of more substantial service. And apropos, sir," he added, "now that it strikes me, allow me to ask, whether the circumstance of one man, however humble, referring for a character to another man, however afflicted, does not argue more or less of moral worth in the latter?

It seems to mean "I would or I could", but I am not sure, is this an idiomatic phrase? I doubt it. What do you make of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Would I could" here simply means "I wish I could".

The meaning matches up with this definition (under "will, v.1") from the Oxford English Dictionary:

> [...] with ellipsis of 1st pers. pron. as an expression of longing = ‘I wish’, ‘O that’

This definition is marked archaic, so I think that it was archaic when Melville used it.

For more examples of "I would I should" from slightly earlier see [The Waverley Novels, Volume 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=XaQ9AAAAYAAJ&pg=RA4-PA16&dq="I+would+I+could".) (1839) and [Book of Martyrs](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pn4sAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA3-PA7&lpg=RA3-PA7&dq="I+would+I+could+do".) (1831). In [Kallundborg Church](https://books.google.com/books?id=hsxNAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA377&lpg=PA377&dq="Would+I+might+die+now+in+thy+stead!".) (1865) there's an example of the pronoun being omitted: "Would I might die now in thy stead!"

Answer (score 2):

The word "would" has been used instead of "would that" in the sentence.The phrase  would (that) is used in formal English to make a strong wish.

The more common and idiomatic is "I wish (that) I could have been......

Comment: "Would that I could" means "I wish I could have been"? Weird.

Comment: According to Cambridge Dictionary: "would that ...formal used to express a strong will or desire.  Would rhat she could see her famous son now".

Answer (score 1):

It means "I wish that I could", and you'll also come across it as "I would *that* I could".

It is not idiomatic now. It is archaic. Educated native speakers will recognise it, but would rarely say it except when looking for a certain effect.